# ConfigParser with no delimiter

Tags: python, configparser

Using Python 3.5 and ConfigParser.

I want to use a config file like this:

```
[Section]
key1
key2
key3
```

i.e. no values. By default ConfigParser requires values but I can pass `allow_no_values=True` to the constructor to handle that.

However the parser will still try to split on the delimiters which by default are `('=', ':')`. Thus my lines can't include any of them by default. But I don't want to delimit on anything - none of my lines will ever have a value.

Passing delimiters=() or [] or None does not work. If using an empty list it complains that `option '' in section 'Section' already exists` while if None I get `'NoneType' is not iterable`.

So is there no way to make sure that splitting never happens ? It does not feel optimal that I have to specify some char that I "hope" will never be used.

Comment: Your "config" file is actually just a data file. Read and parse it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `delimiters=('\n',)` which in theory means the key/value delimiter is a newline, which will never happen because the line delimiter is also a newline and it seems to take precedence.